# What is a good code design for button interaction similar to a radio button?

Tags: android, flutter, design-patterns, dart

I would like to make an user interaction that works like radio button, hence only one item can be active in the list. Instead of a radio button graphics, I'd like to use the ListItem widget.

Hence, I'd like to:

- ListItem A: On tap, 'activate' the list item.
- ListItem B: On tap, 'deactivate' the current active and activate this ListItem.

What is the best algorithm architecture to do this?

I tried to use the architecture in the example below. The problem is that it does not track which list item is clicked, hence it change the 'state' of all the children of the parent at the same time.

````
//------------------------ ParentWidget --------------------------------

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  bool _active = false;

  void _handleTapboxChanged(bool newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _active = newValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded (
            ListView.builder(
             itemCount: listOfBoxes.length,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                 return TapboxB(
                     active: _active,
                     onChanged: _handleTapboxChanged,
                      ),
              }
            )
     )
  }
}

//------------------------- TapboxB ----------------------------------

class TapboxB extends StatelessWidget {
  TapboxB({Key key, this.active: false, @required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  final bool active;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  void _handleTap() {
    onChanged(!active);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _handleTap,
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        width: 200.0,
        height: 200.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: active ? Colors.lightGreen[700] : Colors.grey[600],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/askNilesh/radio_button

Comment: Create one variable named : selectedListItem, and store selected item in that, in both item's tap event store value in same variable and then retrieve that to perform simple conditions

Comment: Why? If you need too many items then selection as radio group is a bad pattern, if you need to add radio buttons programatically then use the radio button constructor and then addView from the radio group, if you need a list then use recyclerview and use an object like {isSelected: Boolean, country: String}

Answer (score 0):

Try this just copy paste into [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter) to see the result

```
class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int currentActiveItem = -1;
  final listItems = [
    'Albania',
    'Andorra',
    'Armenia',
    'Austria',
    'Azerbaijan',
    'Belarus',
    'Belgium',
    'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
    'Bulgaria',
    'Croatia',
    'Cyprus',
    'Czech Republic',
    'Denmark',
    'Estonia'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listItems.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              color: currentActiveItem == index ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentActiveItem = index;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  listItems[index],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Modify as your requirement !




//default view is to be empty without any selection
  //If you want to pre-select, then assign one of the option
  String selection = 'nil';
  final List<String> list = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (con, ind) {
            return ListTile(
                leading: Container(
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: selection == list[ind]
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.black,
                          width: 1.0),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      width: 10,
                      height: 10,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: selection == list[ind]
                            ? Colors.green
                            : Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: selection == list[ind]
                                ? Colors.green
                                : Colors.black,
                            width: 1.0),
                      ),
                    )),
                title: Text(list[ind]),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selection = list[ind];
                  });
                });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]